# importdata gives value error in Google Sheet

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get data via importdata, but got an error.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTDATA(E2,"//div[@class='sum-data']"))
```

Error:

> IMPORTDATA delimiter value is //div[@class='sum-data']. It should be a single character that is not a double quote or a blank space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use IMPORTXML, not IMPORTDATA to get the data.

```
=IMPORTXML(E2,"//div[@class='sum-data']")
```

[IMPORTXML documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en&ref_topic=9199554)